# CDH6.1: GOT Error creating database Manager sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, sqoop, cloudera

I can't import data from SQL Server to HDFS using sqoop.
I try with this sentence:

```
sqoop import --driver com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDrive --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx:1433;database=xxxxx" --connection-manager directive --table T_tipo_informe --username <MyUsername> --password <MyPassword> --as-parquetfile --target-dir /user/woombatc/t_tipo_informe --m 1 --delete-target-dir
```

The result of this is driver `cannot be cast to org.apache.sqoop.manager.ManagerFactory`

[image: Stack trace]

Comment: It's better to add your stack trace as text in your post rather than as an image.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to post your password in that command publicly on the internet? I hope this is just a test password that you are not really using. If you *are* using it you should change it now and then flag your post with a custom flag explaining to the moderator who will review your request that you would like to *have the edit history redacted so that future readers won't see the password in the command*. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Also, please use text for the stacktrace. It's easier to read and to copy-paste, which makes helping you easier

Comment: I say this because your profile says you are working at a company called "Woombat" as far as I understand that and you are using a username and password that look like they belong to that company. Posting company user passwords on the internet might be something your company doesn't like...